# Embedded tomcat with java ee 7 websocket

Tags: java, tomcat

i have this simple websocket

```
@ServerEndpoint(
        value="/data",
        encoders = {WsCommandEncoder.class},
        decoders = {WsCommandDecoder.class}
)
public class DataWebSocket {
   //...impl
}
```

and i initialize my embedded tomcat in the main function

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(6000);

    //how do i add the websocket to my tomcat instance?

    String webDir = "/web";
    tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webDir).getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + webDir).getAbsolutePath());
    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();


}
```

i have never used embedded tomcat before, usually there was the web.xml but i dont want to use webxml and i want to add the end point directly in code, so how do i add the websocket to my tomcat instance?

i am using Tomcat 8.0.9 and java ee 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for the Tomcat unit tests - particularly those for WebSocket. There are lots of examples of adding endpoints via code.

Comment: i did look they were all about adding servelets, no websocket examples

Comment: Then you didn't look very hard. http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/test/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/TestWsRemoteEndpoint.java?view=annotate

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example. straight forward once you get the dependencies right.

https://github.com/robmayhew/embedded-tomcat-websocket-example